# Dynamics 365/CRM Chrome Debugger not working correctly

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've spent more time on this than I care to admit but was hoping for some help in understanding the cause of the problem. I have a basic HTML web resource in Dynamics 365 (v9.1.0.9228) and in order to get the global context I must include the following:

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/getglobalcontext-clientglobalcontext.js.aspx

The problem is that when I do... the Chrome debugger loses its place in the document. The execution stops at the breakpoint(s) but the current line is not highlighted this means no way to step into/over the lines or indeed know what line we are on at any given point. I can see however that the code is being executed due to my output to console (See code in footer).

I have tested this across:

- Multiple D365 online instances (v9.1.0.9228)
- Multiple development machines running Chrome (v77.0.3865.90)

Literally stripped back the code to very basic HTML. Interestingly, this issue does not occur in IE? The only workaround I have found is rather than having inline JS within the head tags place it a separate file instead and reference from the HTML web resource, Chrome then seems to have no issues in stopping on right line and highlighting the correct line as we debug BUT only functions within that library. If the HTML web resource has inline script the issue will still be present within that scope.

**head**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function registerEvents() {
            debugger;
            console.log("in registerEvents v2.0.3");
            testButton = document.getElementById("test");
            testButton.onclick = test;
        }

        function test() {
            debugger;
            console.log("in Test v2.0.3");
        }

    </script>
```

**body**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        registerEvents();
    </script>

    <p>In chrome debugger v2.0.3</p>
    <button id="test">Test</button>
```

I would like to understand if I am doing something wrong here as it seems to be a bug within Chrome DevTools itself given this works on all other browsers when debugging? The actual code here is almost irrelevant as the issue occurs whenever "ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" is referenced, if we comment out that line the Chrome debugger works as expected.